# ELCB Trips when connected

Tags: power, meter

I am facing very strange issue in my power meter & wiring. i am residing in Group society. following is my setup.

1. electricity digital Meter is installed at bottom with a circuit breaker out of my house.
2. i have ELCB installed which acts as circuit breaker for electricity of my house
3. and other small MCBs are installed for regular electricity.
4. some MCBs are installed for high-Power switches which are actually for ACs and Geysers.

5) i have relay switch installed in main circuit box which switch between Main power and Gen-set power(in time of power cut), so high-Power switches ( point 4 above) are not relayed , they directly get power from phase as high-Power switches are not connected to Gen-set.

**issue i am facing**.

- ELCB is always tripping when connected to home wiring. so my electrician has  separated that from ELCB and now ElCB only controlling high-Power switches & it does not trip.
- if i switch off the all MCbs and ELCB my power meter show that i have consumed some electricity. 3 units in 12 hours, which is huge.
- if i switch off the circuit breaker which is installed with meter (point 1 on top) at outside of my house. then meter stops and does not show any units.

I called electrician he is unable to find the fault :(

**why it consume power when all the MCBs are down? also how can i troubleshoot why it trips?**
i will share the picture of meter later.

Comment: By group society, are you referring to apartments? By 3 units, is that kilowatt hours? I'm not sure what question you are asking, would you clarify what question you'd like us to answer?

Comment: Yes Apartment, where electricity is distributed via society and Genset installed in case of power failure. then relay switches between those. secondly yes kilowatt hours, i have updated my question. let me know if still any question.

Comment: Something is connected (wired) wrong, that's the general answer. You need to contact a new electrician. As a secondary possibility, the meter could be bad. Contact the utility company and see what they say.

Comment: i am getting my meter checked next weeken that could be one of the reason. but my suspicion also on wiring as ELCB gets down when connected as mother breaker.  how can i get detect the problem at main circuit board where all mcbs are intalled. one electrician says.. whole wiring has to be checked . but i think there should be way to detect it without checking all wiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why it consume power when all the MCBs are down?

The short answer is: It can't. The only way power can be consumed is if you have a complete circuit.

Someone has miswired something if you are getting current flow with all the circuit breakers turned off.

You need an experienced electrician to troubleshoot this problem. Apparently the one you called is not that good at it.

Good luck!